# Is any way to reduce code duplication in different class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I apologise for the unclear title, I have trouble to put words on what I want to do.

Very often when I work, I find myself doing classes like this :

```
class MyModel:
    def __init__(self, my_dict):
        self.x = my_dict.get("x")
        self.y = my_dict.get("y")
        self.z = my_dict.get("z")

    def to_json(self):
        return {'x': self.x, 'y': self.y, 'z': self.z}

class MyModel2:
    def __init__(self, my_dict):
            self.a = my_dict.get("a")
            self.b = my_dict.get("b")

    def to_json(self):
        return {'a': self.a, 'b': self.b}
```

So I'm looking for a solution to avoid doing a lot of code duplication, for exemple not having to redefine the `to_json` method since it's always take class attribute to put it in a dictionnary
A exemple of solution can be something like this:

```
from typing import List

class MyModel(MyMagicClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = int
        self.y = str
        self.z = List[int]
```

I'm not looking for a particular solution but just a way to reduce code duplication.

Thank you !

Comment: Do you have any requirements ? maybe the `pydantic` BaseModel will do the job ? 
https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/ 
if you use the BaseModel as a base class all your models then inherit the `.json()` and `.dict()` methods

Comment: it really looks like what I want, you can easily create by doing MyModel (**my_dict), what would be even better is that a similar solution exists with the standard library which will prevent me from adding dependencies

Comment: so from standard library check `dataclasses` this module got functions like `asdict` and also decorator to transform class into dataclass

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, by inheriting you can avoid this problem.

```
class myMagicClass:
    def toJson(self):
        print("I am mymagicClass")
        
class myNormalClass(myMagicClass):
    def run(self):
        print("My normal Class ",end="")
        self.toJson()
        

obj = myNormalClass()
obj.toJson()
obj.run()

#I am mymagicClass
#My normal Class I am mymagicClass
```

child classes and objects created from them have methods of parent childs.
You can make a parent class that have common methods and then inherit them.